# Enter username and password before loading the URL to load the URL

Tags: perl, activestate

I am trying to open a website using ActiveState's [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) (`WWW::Mechanize`).

```
$mech -> get($url);
```

The above mentioned line shows an error:

> Error GETing URL : Unauthorized

The URL has a form in which the credentials are to be entered and only on submitting the form will it load the URL. I.e., before the URL loads, it asks for the username and password. How do I keep the URL on hold and load it after entering the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **submit_form** method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get("http://www.example.com/login");
$mech->submit_form(with_fields => {
    USERNAME => '*****',
    PASSWORD => '*****'
});

my $url = "http://www.example.com/page_test";
$mech->get($url);
```